# Images Not Appearing in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I've tried searching on the web including Stack Overflow and haven't found a solution.

So I just finished developing a website on Mac and it looks fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

When I go to use Windows, everything shows up fine in Internet Explorer, but not on Chrome and Firefox. Some images don't load in Chrome and Firefox only on PC!

I inspected the elements with both browsers and it looks fine.

Here is the code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/appenze"><img style ="height:130px;width:130px;margin-right:-20px;" src="images/facebook_old.png" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="https://plus.google.com/+Appenze/"><img class ="social-media-pic" src="images/GooglePlus-Logo-02.png" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/appenze-technologies"><img class ="social-media-pic" src="images/transparent-Linkedin-logo-icon.png" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="https://twitter.com/appenze"><img class ="social-media-pic" src="images/twitter-icon-square.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The images are all in PNG format and in RGB color. They're all 16-bit images. The only image that loads is "transparent-Linkedin-logo-icon.png".

What is going on with Chrome and Firefox on Windows? The version of Windows I'm using is Windows 8.1.

By the way, here is a link to the JSFiddle page with all the code: http://jsfiddle.net/57y3J/

Lastly, the website is live. Here is the link to the problem page if you guys want to test it:
http://www.appenze.com/social.html

**UPDATE**

This problem only seems to be happening for Chrome and Firefox on Windows while running the "Adblock Plus" extension.

I am running Adblock Plus on both Chrome and Firefox on Mac and the images appear normally. I also have Adblock Plus installed on Internet Explorer on my PC and the images are still loading properly.

Comment: Could you give us a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you using the correct path? If "images" is in the in the root you may need to do /images/nameOfImage

Comment: I'm using the correct path. I've checked the path many times.

Comment: try `PNG` instead of `png` and see if that helps

Comment: not quiet sure if this is the solution but you have a blank space in `style ="height:130px;`, should be `style="height:130px;` + in every single `class ="XXX` again blank spaces

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57y3J/

Comment: here 4 icons loading fine. using Firefox in Windows

Comment: @dippas, which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, Firefox, works fine to me.

Comment: Is anyone who's having success with viewing the images on Windows using Chrome or Firefox running the "Adblock Plus" extension?

Comment: @bkhosh2 im using ff28 and adb plus.. still works fine for me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has nothing to do with programming and was caused by a mis-configuring of a separate application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guys are going to laugh when you read this.

I've solved the image loading problem. When I disable the "Adblock Plus" extension that run in both the browsers and refresh the page, the images appear normally.

This problem only seems to be happening for Chrome and Firefox on Windows. I am running Adblock Plus on both Chrome and Firefox on Mac and the images appear normally. I also have Adblock Plus installed on Internet Explorer on my PC and the images are still loading properly.

I still don't know how to fix this for people that are using the Adblock Plus extension though.

Comment: im using ff28 and adb plus.. still works fine for me so it might be the list you choosed   on adb

Comment: I just have the the default list chosen on adb