# Inline image loads in IE but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, image-load

In chrome / firefox I get

[image]

In IE I get

[image]

The code is

```
<li><a  target="_blank" href="file:///M:\CarpentariaShire\MapInfo_Tables\Vector_Data\Infrastructure\Transport\Roads\Road_Features\Signs\Signs_2017_005\{{feature.Image_Name.value}}"> <img src="M:\CarpentariaShire\MapInfo_Tables\Vector_Data\Infrastructure\Transport\Roads\Road_Features\Signs\Signs_2017_005\{{feature.Image_Name.value}}" alt="{{feature.Image_Name.value}}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" </a> </li>
```

Where
{{feature.Image_Name.value}}
gets the image name from the table

This is being run in MapInfo, Spectrum Spatial Analyst (SSA) as a info template.

I looked at [Images Not Appearing in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165141/images-not-appearing-in-chrome-and-firefox) and [Images not loading in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930864/images-not-loading-in-firefox) but I am not running an Ad blocker.

**How can I get the images to load in chrome/firefox like in IE?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local file access is not allowed in Chrome and Firefox for security reason.

You need to use a virtual directory or move your image folder into your web directory.

Comment: surprising IE allows and the others don't.